# Validate Form before Submit or keep if filled in case of failure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I need help with a form validation with PHP. I would like to check if fields "mails" and "d_place" exist in DB before submiting the form. In case any of them already exists, you have to complete the whole form again. So, in order to make it more friendly for the user, it would be great to check this condition before submiting the form, or at least be able to keep the values entered, so that the user only changes the field that produces the error.

Here, my form:

```
<form method="post" action="save_place.php">
     <section id="costado2">

        <div id="direx">
            <label for="search_new_places">Direccion del Local</label>
            <input type="text" name="d_place" placeholder="Direccion de Local.."  id="search_new_places" class='form-control' required>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="place_id" id="place_id"/>

        <div id="nombre_loc">
            <label for="place">Nombre del Local</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de Local.." name="n_place" id="n_place" class='form-control' required>  
        </div>


        <?php


        //Get all country data
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM provincias ORDER BY provincia ASC");

        //Count total number of rows
        $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

        $queryr = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rubros ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC");
        $rowCountr = $queryr->num_rows;

        ?>

        <div id="descrip">
             <select name="rubro" id="n_description" name="n_description" class='form-control' required>
                <option value="">Selecciona Rubro</option>
                <?php
                if($rowCount > 0){
                    while($row = $queryr->fetch_assoc()){ 
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['NOMBRE'].'</option>';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<option value="">Rubro No Disponible</option>';
                }


                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="pro">
            <select name="country" id="country" class='form-control' required>
                <option value="">Selecciona Provincia</option>
                <?php
                if($rowCount > 0){
                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['provincia']).'</option>';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<option value="">Provincia no Disponible</option>';
                }

                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

         <div id="loc">
            <select name="state" id="state" class='form-control' required>
                <option value="">Selecciona Localidad</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="tel">
            <label>Telefono</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" name="d_tel" placeholder="Telefono.." class='form-control'>
        </div>

        <div id="mail">
            <label>Mail</label>
            <br>
            <input name="mails" id="mails" type="email" placeholder="Mail.." class='form-control' pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" required>
        </div>

        <div id="pass">
          <label><span>Password</span></label> <input pattern=".{5,10}" name="passw" id="passw" type="password" maxlength="10" placeholder="Password.." class='form-control' required>
        </div>

        <div id="repass">
          <label><span>Repetir Password</span></label> <input pattern=".{5,10}" name="reps" id="reps" type="password" maxlength="10" placeholder="Repetir Password.." class='form-control' required>
        </div>

        <div id="bot3">
            <input type="submit" id="btn_save" name="btn_save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="GUARDAR"/>
            <input id="lat" name="lat" value="" type="hidden" >
            <input id="lng" name="lng" value="" type="hidden" >
        </div>

        <div id="bot4">
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; VOLVER</a>
        </div>

    </section>
</form>
```

And here, the page where I make the validation:

```
<?php
 require_once('DB.php');

  $place = $_POST['n_place'];
  $description = $_POST['rubro'];
  $latitude = $_POST['lat'];
  $longitude = $_POST['lng'];
  $direccion = $_POST['d_place'];
  $provincia = $_POST['country'];
  $localidad = $_POST['state'];
  $telefono = $_POST['d_tel'];
  $mail = $_POST['mails'];
  $pass = $_POST['passw'];
  $repass = $_POST['reps'];
  $fecha = date("Y/m/d");

  $di = ("SELECT * FROM locales WHERE DIRECCION = '$direccion'");
  $querydi = $dbh->prepare($di);
  $querydi->execute(array($direccion));

  $q = ("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE MAIL = '$mail'");
  $ql = ("SELECT * FROM locales WHERE MAIL = '$mail'");
  $query = $dbh->prepare($q);
  $queryl = $dbh->prepare($ql);
  $query->execute(array($mail));
  $queryl->execute(array($mail));

  session_start();
  if (($query->rowCount() == 0) && ($queryl->rowCount() == 0) && ($querydi->rowCount() == 0) && ($pass == $repass)) {

$dbp->query("INSERT INTO locales (NOMBRE, SUCURSAL, ESTADO, ID_LOCALIDAD, LAT, LNG, ID_RUBRO, ID_ROL, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, MAIL, PASSWORD, FECHA_ALTA) VALUES ('$place', 1,1,'$localidad', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$description', 3, '$direccion', '$telefono', '$mail', '$pass', '$fecha')");

$place_id = $dbp->insert_id;

    $_SESSION['msg_box'] = array("Local ingresado exitosamente", "success");
    echo header("location:login.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg_box'] = array("Hubo un error al insertar el local", "warning");
    if ($querydi->rowCount() > 0) {
        $_SESSION['msg_box'][0] .= "<br>La dirección ya se encuentra registrada.";
    }
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0 || $queryl->rowCount() > 0) {
    $_SESSION['msg_box'][0] .= "<br>El mail ingresado ya se encuentra registrado.";
    }   
    echo header("location:registrar_local.php");
}


?>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use AJAX to validate the form.